# Are Vaishnavas & Smartas completely uninformed about third eye awakening?

Tags: vaishnavism, adi-shankaracharya, shaivism, smriti, shaktism

Supernatural powers are mainly found in Shaiv & Shaakt scriptures and I don't think a single Vaishnav guru or Shankaracharya has third eye powers.

Is third eye completely missing from Vaishnav & Smaart scriptures - making them completely uninformed? If not please give scriptural reference.

Comment: In brahmasutra bhashya, Adi Shankara mentions that except powers of creation of the world etc (which only God possesses), all other powers are present for the realized souls - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49039/23407

Comment: there's no mention of third eye there. Adi Shankar didn't have third eye power himself just like shankaracharyas today

Comment: If each power is mentioned individually, it will run into pages. Hence a generic mention of - all powers except powers of creation etc. of the world.

Comment: So there's not a single page or even word in all your scriptures? Since third eye doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere outside Shaiv & Shaakt shankaracharya could mean some other powers... This is just pure speculation since there are no mantras/sadhnas for third eye awakening or kundalini jagran mentioned in Vaishnav or Smaart texts to my knowledge